# add 3 maps into one map in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, java-ee-6

i have 3 maps like that

```
map1 ={(1,"kamal"),(2,"amal")(3,"nimal")};
map2 ={(1,"gold fish"),(2,"carft")(3,"angel")};
map3 ={(1,"cat"),(2,"dog")(3,"rabit")};
```

I need add those to one newMap

then i tried

```
 newMap.puttAll(map1);
 newMap.puttAll(map2);
 newMap.puttAll(map3);
```

out put is {(1,"cat"),(2,"dog")(3,"rabit")}

map1 and map 2 is replaced by map 3.
i need add these 3 maps to newMap.

wanted out put is 
`{(1,"kamal"),(2,"amal")(3,"nimal"),(4,"gold fish"),(5,"carft")(6,"angel"),(7,"cat"),(8,"dog")(9,"rabit")}`

Thing is my map has same key how can I solve this

Comment: You can't repeat keys in a map, values are replaced.

Comment: What do you want your map to look like?

Comment: i wanted like that {(1,"kamal"),(2,"amal")(3,"nimal"),(4,"gold fish"),(5,"carft")(6,"angel"),(7,"cat"),(8,"dog")(9,"rabit")}

Answer (score 4):

Quoting first line of javadoc for [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> An object that maps keys to values. **A map cannot contain duplicate keys**; each key can map to at most one value.

Quoting javadoc for [`put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

You're getting exactly the result as documented. Last entry for each key wins.

---

**Update**

Since you've now said you want result to be:

> {(1,"kamal"),(2,"amal")(3,"nimal"),(4,"gold fish"),(5,"carft")(6,"angel"),(7,"cat"),(8,"dog")(9,"rabit")}

You don't seem to care about the key, just the values, so add all values with new incrementing key:

```
int newKey = 0;
for (String value : map1.values())
    newMap.put(++newKey, value);
for (String value : map2.values())
    newMap.put(++newKey, value);
for (String value : map3.values())
    newMap.put(++newKey, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to give the best answer, but if the keys are `1`, `2`, `3`,..., `9`, it would make more sense to use `List` rather than `Map`. Then you can use `addAll` to add all elements from one `List` to another.

Remember that `List` indices start at `0` so you would get the first item by doing `list.get(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer;

@SafeVarargs
private static Map<Integer, String> putAllValuesToMapStartingWithKey(int startKey, Map<Integer, String>... sourceMaps) {
    final Map<Integer, String> destinationMap = new TreeMap<>();
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(startKey);
    for (Map<Integer, String> sourceMap : sourceMaps) {
        MapUtils.populateMap(destinationMap, sourceMap.values(), new Transformer<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer transform(final String input) {
                return counter.getAndIncrement();
            }
        });
    }
    return destinationMap;
}
```

Main class for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(1, "kamal");
        put(2, "amal");
        put(3, "nimal");
    }};
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(1, "gold fish");
        put(2, "carft");
        put(3, "angel");
    }};
    Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(1, "cat");
        put(2, "dog");
        put(3, "rabit");
    }};
    Map<Integer, String> map = putAllValuesToMapStartingWithKey(1, map1, map2, map3);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is create a Map of type `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and add manually.

```
/*
 *@param HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> The map to be generated 
 *@param HashMap<Integer, String> The map to add
 *@returns HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> The final map after adding the given hashmap to it. 
*/

public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> addToMap(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>map, HashMap<Integer, String> mp)
 {
 Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
 List<String> list;
  if(map.containsKey(pair.getKey())
    list = map.get(pair.getKey());
  else
     List<String> list = new ArrayList();
   list.add(pair.getValue());
   map.put(pair.getKey, list);
 }
return map;
}
```

---

If you want the ouput to be with a incremental key, it becomes simple.

Iterate, maintain an iterating key

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>> maps = new ArrayList();
maps.add(map1);
maps.add(map2);

for(int i = 0, index = 1; i < maps.size(); ++i)
{
 Iterator it = maps[i].entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
  HashMap.put(index , mp.getValue());
  index ++;
  }
}
```